# pre_replace a string to capitalize each word that follows an underscore

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Here is a sample string:
`hello_world_again`

So it would be converted to:
`HelloWorldAgain`

So it should be able to remove the underscore and capitalize the next letter. The first letter should also be capitalize. I found this: `preg_replace('/(?<! )(?<!^)[A-Z]/', '_$0', $val)`

But now I want to reverse the process. Much help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regular expressions alone will not work here. However, you can use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) instead:

```
$val = 'hello_world_again';
function match_toupper($m) {
    return strtoupper($m[1]);
}
$val = preg_replace_callback('/(?:^|_)([a-z])/', 'match_toupper', $val);
echo $val; // HelloWorldAgain
```

In PHP 5.3 or later, can also use an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php):

```
$val = 'hello_world_again';
$val = preg_replace_callback('/(?:^|_)([a-z])/', 
    function ($m) {
        return strtoupper($m[1]);
    }, $val);
echo $val; // HelloWorldAgain
```

Also, if you ignore all the warnings and cautions about the [`e` modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), this will work too:

```
$val = 'hello_world_again';
$val = preg_replace('/(?:^|_)([a-z])/e', 'strtoupper($1)', $val);
echo $val; // HelloWorldAgain
```

And here's another solution that avoids regular expressions entirely:

```
$val = 'hello_world_again';
$val = implode('', array_map(ucfirst, explode('_', $val)));
echo $val; // HelloWorldAgain
```

Comment: You must have seen me typing that :) +1.

Answer (score 1):

Just find using this, use a callback replace to convert $1 to upper

```
 #  (?:^|_)(.)

 (?: ^ | _ )
 ( . )             # (1)
```

Edit: If you run into a situation where the first character is NOT an alpha.
In the replace, convert $2 to upper if it has length, then catenate $1 and $2
This strips out all _'s, and leaves any punctuation.

```
 # (?i)(?:^|_)\s*([^a-z\s]*)([a-z])?

 (?i)
 (?: ^ | _ )
 \s* 
 ( [^a-z\s]* )     # (1)
 ( [a-z] )?        # (2)
```

Comment: People are quick on these easy answers.

Answer (score 1):

From PHP 5.4.32, 5.5.16 on you can use `str_replace('_','',ucwords($str,'_'));`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the easiest way of doing this. since PHP 5.0, [ucword()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php) is available to capitalize every word of a string.

```
$val = 'hello_world_again';
$val = str_replace('_','',ucwords($val,'_'));
echo $val; //HelloWorldAgain
```